# Click not completing due to Css Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the search icon the event fires as it should. But when the search box is expanded the click doesn't fire, instead, the search box goes back to being small again.

**Edit: See claudios snippet for the behaviour I mean**

Edit 2: **`.mouseDown()` instead of `.click()` works.** So it seems that when I click on the search icon, focus in the searchbox is lost which makes it go back to it's original size. This would appear to happen before the mouseUp event which means the coords for the search icon are no longer the same as the `.click()` event.

[image] [image]

So I fired up the debugger, set the search box to focus and set my breakpoints and it works. Can I assume my Css transitions are preventing the click action from completing? And if so how do I get the click in before the css takes effect?

Here is all the relevant code:

```js
jQuery('.icon-wrapper').click(function(){
    var searchQuery = jQuery('#searchBox').val();
    if(searchQuery != ""){
        alert("I got clicked!");
        return;
    }
});
```

```css
.expandable-search input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 80%;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}


input[type=search] {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
    width: 55px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
    -moz-border-radius: 10em;
    border-radius: 10em;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}


.expandable-search input[type=search] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: transparent;
}

.expandable-search input[type=search]:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}

span.icon-wrapper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.expandable-search input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 130px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: auto;
}
.expandable-search input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
.expandable-search input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

.expandable-search .icon-wrapper:after {
   content: url("http://ak-static.legacy.net/obituaries/images/obituary/obituaryportal/icon_search.png");
   font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
   position: absolute;
   left: 20px;
   top: 10px;
   color: #212121;
   font-size: 20px;
   left: 50px;
   top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="expandable-search vertical-center">
    <input type="search" id="searchBox">
    <span class="icon-wrapper"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: It looks like you code works fine in the snippet - the field expands and contracts as focus is gained/lost respectively. What are you expecting to happen instead? Also note that transition has no effect on click events being raised.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem is that when the field is expanded and I click on the search icon, the click event isn't firing

Comment: Can you provide js fiddle link? with the code and issue?

Comment: @rory could you please add the CSS for the `.icon-wrapper` element to the snippet. It may be possible to pass the `:focus` to the neighbouring input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan done. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Veer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dq0so3cr/) you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand the issue you want that the icon has two jobs

1. first expand the search input
2. after that act like a submit button. Maybe even check if the search input has value. If yes, do the request for example a post via ajax, otherwise do nothing or display a message that the user has to fill in something.

**Working with CSS `:focus`**

One problem is that each time you click now on the icon, the search input will lose its focus because your icon is not content of this input. So the `:focus` you add with CSS will be removed. One solution would be to work with pseudo elements and simply put the icon in the `:after` or `:before` content, but since you can't use any of them on inputs, you have to do a workaround to achieve what you want. So in your case I think the only way is to simulate the focus via JavaScript.

You could achieve this with following code

**HTML**

```
<div id="search">
  <button id="search-button">
    <i class="ion-ios-search"></i>
  </button>
  <input type="search" id="search-input" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

#search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
}

#search-button,
#search-input {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#search-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search-button i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

#search-input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 0;
}

.clicked + #search-input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $searchButton = $("#search-button");
var $searchInput = $("#search-input");

$searchButton.click(function() {
  $searchInput.focus();
  if ($searchInput.val() !== "") {
    alert("post");
  } else if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked") && $searchInput.val() === "") {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("clicked") && $searchInput.val() === "") {
    alert("fill");
  }
});

$(document).click(function(e){
  if(!$("#search").has(e.target).length && $searchInput.val() === ""){
    $searchButton.removeClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

```js
var $searchButton = $("#search-button");
var $searchInput = $("#search-input");

$searchButton.click(function() {
  $searchInput.focus();
  if ($searchInput.val() !== "") {
    alert("post");
  } else if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked") && $searchInput.val() === "") {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("clicked") && $searchInput.val() === "") {
    alert("fill something in");
  }
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (!$("#search").has(e.target).length && $searchInput.val() === "") {
    $searchButton.removeClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
#search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#search-button,
#search-input {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
#search-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#search-button i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
#search-input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 0;
}
.clicked + #search-input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
  <button id="search-button">
    <i class="ion-ios-search"></i>
  </button>
  <input type="search" id="search-input" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working in here. Maybe there's something to do with your icon css or something.

```js
$('.icon-wrapper').click(function() {
  var searchQuery = jQuery('#searchBox').val();
  if (searchQuery != "") {
    alert(searchQuery);
    searchSubmit(searchQuery);
    return;
  }
});
```

```css
.expandable-search input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 80%;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

input[type=search] {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.expandable-search input[type=search] {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.expandable-search input[type=search]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

span.icon-wrapper:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expandable-search input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
}


.expandable-search input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.expandable-search input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.icon-wrapper img {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="expandable-search vertical-center">
    <input type="search" id="searchBox">
    <span class="icon-wrapper">
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png">
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But the alert isn't firing?

Comment: it fires try to click it once more. It's because of your css